# Proper way to mock classes and assert on calls to methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to write unit tests for `Bar` that makes calls to `Foo`'s method `read()`. I have added the patch command in `setUp()` because other tests will use this patch as well.

### Question

How can I check that the `read()` function was called with the arguments that I am expecting?

### Code

`foo.py`

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = {'foo': 1}

    def read(self, name):
        return self.table[name]
```

`bar.py`

```
import foo

class Bar(object):
    def act(self):
        a = foo.Foo()
        return a.read('foo')
```

`test_bar.py`

```
import bar
import unittest
from mock import patch

class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo_mock = patch('bar.foo.Foo', autospec=True).start()
        self.addCleanup(patch.stopall)

    def test_can_call_foo_with_correct_arguments(self):
        a = bar.Bar()
        a.act()
        self.foo_mock.read.assert_called_once_with('foo')
```

#### Output

`python -m unittest discover`

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_call_foo_with_correct_arguments (test_bar.TestBar)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test_dir/test_bar.py", line 12, in test_can_call_foo_with_correct_arguments
    self.foo_mock.read.assert_called_once_with('foo')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 845, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried? `self.foo_mock.return_value.read.assert_called_once_with('foo')`?

Comment: You could try using a real foo `self.foo = Foo()` and then mocking out the read call: `self.foo.read = Mock()`?

Comment: Or `patch.object` might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/5044894/1389752

Comment: @SimeonVisser You were right. I had forgot to call `a.act()` in my test for this minimal example. Thank you! I have updated the question as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`read` is a method on *instances* of `Foo`. You want to check for the mock `return_value` to access the instance. After all, you create the instance by *calling* `foo.Foo()`:

```
foo_instance = self.foo_mock.return_value
foo_instance.read.assert_called_once_with('foo')
```

Note that you are patching `foo.Foo`; using `bar.foo.Foo` is the same object, but a round-about way of specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Mocks have many pitfalls, this is why [I wrote a helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to generate the asserts for me.

To use it, you should add the following lines after `a.act()`:

```
import mock_autogen.generator
print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(mock=self.foo_mock, name='self.foo_mock'))
```

This outputs these lines:

```
assert 1 == self.foo_mock.call_count
self.foo_mock.assert_called_once_with()
self.foo_mock.return_value.read.assert_called_once_with('foo')
```

The first two are generated because foo is a class which was instanced. The third line is the line you were originally looking for.

So no more guesswork, be methodical and use [mock-generator](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/).